# 'registerForDraggedTypes:' Audio Only

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, audio, nsview

I am trying to write a small Cocoa application. It involves an NSView in which I want the user to be able to drag audio files (from, for example, the Finder). However, I do not know how to allow **only audio files** to be dropped into the NSView.

I managed to get this far, thinking this would work:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self=[super initWithCoder:coder];
    if ( self ) {
        NSString *myType = (__bridge NSString *)(UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassNSPboardType, kUTTypeAudio, NULL));
        [self registerForDraggedTypes: [NSArray arrayWithObject:myType]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The above code seems to not allow any files to be dropped into the NSView. I assume this is because `myType` is not valid for use with `registerForDraggedTypes`.

Any help you can provide would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're leaking the string that you Created using that function. You would need to use `__bridge_transfer` or `CFBridgingRelease` to make sure the string eventually gets destroyed when it needs to be.

Comment: Is that `-initWithCoder:` method defined in an `NSView` subclass? If it’s a view and it’s loaded from a nib file, that method won’t be executed. Custom views receive `-initWithFrame:` instead.

Comment: Source for @Bavarious's statement: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW19 item 2.b.

Comment: @Bavarious @Peter Hosey That's weird. The `initWithCoder` method does get called (have checked and double checked), the class is a subclass of an `NSView` and is using the 'Custom Class' option in IB. See this sample project from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CocoaDragAndDrop/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000384

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Registering for a type such as `kUTTypeAudio` does not register for dragged files; it registers for dragged audio. It *might* work for accepting audio of any type* dragged in from another application, but will not work for accepting files.

You will need to register for type `kUTTypeFileURL`. Once you do that, any file that the user drags in will light up your drag-destination methods. There is no way to say at this stage “I want files, but only some kinds of files”.

As a drag destination, you need to validate the drag (in `draggingEntered:`). This is where you test whether any of the files are or are not an audio file. You have your choice of three approaches:

- Use the Metadata framework to get each file's content type. Expect this to fail for any file on a volume that doesn't have a Spotlight index.
- Use Launch Services to determine what content type corresponds to a given filename extension. Will fail for any file that doesn't have a filename extension; should work as long as no filename extensions are ambiguous (not a problem for audio, AFAIK, but can be a problem for certain extensions such as “dat”).
- Attempt to interpret each file using your underlying audio API/library, and see whether it succeeds.

If you obtain a content type (UTI) for one of the files, you'll then have to see whether it's one of the types you can handle.

- If you're just playing the audio using NSSound, use `[NSSound soundUnfilteredTypes]`. This returns an array of UTIs, so you're done; you can simply compare incoming UTIs to the ones in this array (using `UTTypeEqual`).
- If you're using Audio File Services (or the next higher-level API, ExtAudioFile) to read each file, use `AudioFileGetGlobalInfo` to get the list of type codes, then use `UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag` to convert each one from an `OSType` to a UTI.
- If you're using some other library, you'll just have to see what that offers for assessing what types it supports.

*If and only if incoming types are checked for conformance to any of your registered types rather than equality. If they are strictly tested for equality to your registered types, you will need to register for the specific audio types you can handle.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your response. For validating the drag, I think the third option sounds best (as I will be mostly working with files on external volumes). The Audio framework I'm using is AVFoundation. I've been looking through Apple's Documentation, and can't seem to find a way of checking `would this file be suitable for use as an AVAsset?`Any ideas on what I could do? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @baxterma: It's rather tricky with AVFoundation, since it's such a deeply asynchronous library. You can create an AVPlayerItem, but its status won't change to `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay` until some time after (and you may not be able to wait for it, if its read attempt happens on the main thread). Your best bet would be to ask AVAsset for the `audiovisualTypes`, then filter that array by which ones conform to `kUTTypeAudio`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I managed to get it working using the system you described above, using `audiovisualTypes` and filtering to `kUTTypeAudio`.